# I want to hide "/blog " from my post's url

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting, blob

my blog url is like www.mysite.com/blog. and post urls are like www.mysite.com/blog/category/post_name. my problem is , I want to hide" /blog " from my post urls. Butblog url should be the same. in blog url "/blog" should show. Can i fix this by using htaccess? or is there any other method I can use?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Go to your Wordpress Admin Area
Navigate to Settings->Permalinks.

Set permalink settings to Postname .
Or try using custom structure :

> /%postname%/

Or try changing site url if it does not work!